# Creating a category page by alphabet

Tags: sort, categories

i'm new to wordpress, and i don't know how to code.
I would like to make a page where all my animes are sorted by alphabet, like in this image
[image: Example]

I've heard about the wp_list_category function, so i made a separate category for each anime. Now the problem is, i dont know how to use the function to make such alphabetic list, as i dont have any experience in coding, so can someone please tell me how to do that?

Thanks in advance

EDIT=
So i've did some search on google, and made this script, but it doesn't work yet, can someone explain what's wrong in this script?

```
<?php
$args = [
    'category_name' => 'on-going',
    '_name__like'   => 'A'   
$terms = get_terms( 'category', $args );
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
    $count = count( $terms );
    $i = 0;
    $term_list = '<p class="my_term-archive">';
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $i++;
        $term_list .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( 'View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain' ), $term->name ) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
        if ( $count != $i ) {
            $term_list .= ' &middot; ';
        }
        else {
            $term_list .= '</p>';
        }
    }
    echo $term_list;
} ?>
```

This script looks so complicated for me, haven't seen one like this before :/

EDIT:
Used this script in the end, thanks for all the help

```
$terms = get_terms('anime-on-going');

if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){    
$term_list = [];    
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    $first_letter = strtoupper($term->name[0]);
    $term_list[$first_letter][] = $term;
}
unset($term);

echo '<ul class="my_term-archive">';

    foreach ( $term_list as $key=>$value ) {
        echo '<h2 class="term-letter">' . $key . '</h2>';

        foreach ( $value as $term ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
        }
    }

echo '</ul>';
}
```

Comment: >i'm new to wordpress, and i don't know how to code.
Step 1st. Learn how to code. http://php.net & http://mysql.com offer nice documentation.

Comment: IIRC this has been answered before. Use the site search

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'm also learning as i'm making this website. So far i've made several things on my website, but this wp_list_categories function is a bit complicated, so some assistance would help me to learn :)

Comment: Sorry, but i've did search before posting this, but i can't find any answer that fix my problem.

I dont know if i were searching with the wrong keyword though.

Comment: Maybe taking a look at the codex for a start at [wp list categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories#Default_Usage) helps. This [get terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms#Default_Usage) gives also info. After that you maybe look [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/149525/15605) also.

Comment: I've read the function thing, but it doesn't explain how to get the first letter. About this [link]http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149489/category-alphabet-list-broken/149525#149525[link], can you please explain some about the script you put there @PieterGoosen ?

Comment: Just use my code as explained [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/149525/31545). Just change the taxonomy name.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks a lot. I've got the page working now :)
http://yahya98.com/on-going/

Comment: Please add your last edit as an answer and accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, i used this script in the end, thanks to Pieter Goosen's post [Category Alphabet List Broken](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/149489/category-alphabet-list-broken/149525#149525)

```
$terms = get_terms('anime-on-going');

if ( !empty( $terms ) && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ){    
$term_list = [];    
foreach ( $terms as $term ){
    $first_letter = strtoupper($term->name[0]);
    $term_list[$first_letter][] = $term;
}
unset($term);

echo '<ul class="my_term-archive">';

    foreach ( $term_list as $key=>$value ) {
        echo '<h2 class="term-letter">' . $key . '</h2>';

        foreach ( $value as $term ) {
            echo '<li><a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '" title="' . sprintf(__('View all post filed under %s', 'my_localization_domain'), $term->name) . '">'     . $term->name . '</a></li>';
        }
    }

echo '</ul>';
}
```